# Calculate definite integral $\int^b_a e^{-x^a}dx $

Tags: integration

Is there any closed form expression for $\int^b_a e^{-x^k}dx$ ?. With $z=x^k$, we have
$\int^{b^k}_{a^k} 1/k e^{-z} z^{1/k-1} dz$. Then I have no idea what to do next. It appears I have a gamma function. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: no closed form for such expresion exists except for a=0 and b=infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no closed form solution except for a special case, as has been articulated in a comment. In case you are interested here it is: 
\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^\alpha}\,dx=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)
\end{align}
EDIT:
Yes, this integral can be expressed in terms of the [incomplete Gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function)  $\Gamma(n,x)$ and $\gamma(n,x)$. 
\begin{align}
I&=\int_a^b e^{-x^k}\,dx \qquad u=x^k\\
I&=\frac{1}{k}\int_{a^k}^{b^k} u^{\frac{1}{k}-1} e^{-u}\,du\\
I&=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)-\frac{1}{k}\,\gamma\left(\frac{1}{k},a^k\right)-\frac{1}{k}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k},b^k\right)
\end{align}
This can even be simplified:
\begin{align} 
\int_a^b e^{-x^k}\,dx=\frac{1}{k}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k},a^k\right)-\frac{1}{k}\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{k},b^k\right)
\end{align}

Comment: Is it even possible to write it in terms of some incomplete gamma functions?